# IEWebGL IE acts strange

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, 3d, webgl

I am currently developing WebGL web application and i'm using IEWebGL plugin to display the 3d model to IE. 
However, IE acts very strange. For example - on the laptop, the 3d model displays and renders perfectly both on IE9 and IE10. And when I try to access the model from the other machine in the room - it displays error, which says 'Error occurs during WebGL context creation: [can't initialize EGL]'.
Both machines are running Windows 7. All other browsers run it without any problems.

I've tried it on several machine's IEs and some of them display it correct, while other don't.
I've also tried updating video card drivers but this didn't help.

Thanks in advance.